# Access a list of columns to be evaluated in a Comprehension Expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, list-comprehension

There is this dataframe called `frame` with columns: `Age`, `Maturity`, `Gender`, `Height` which has values '`PASSED`' or '`FAILED`'.

I want to create a new column called `result` and count the number of a subset of the overall columns as seen in `check_columns` which has the value `PASSED`.

I tried to use a comprehension expression which as seen in this case I wanted it to be evaluated to 2 since the columns `Age` and `Maturity` have `PASSED` while `Gender` has `FAILED` which are present in a subset of columns in `check_columns`.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {'Age':['PASSED'], 'Maturity':['PASSED'],'Gender':['FAILED'], 'Height':['PASSED']}
)
check_columns = ['Age','Maturity','Gender']
frame['result'] = sum([1  if frame[column] =='PASSED' else 0 for column in check_columns ])
```

I tried to used a comprehension with a list but it says this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only the desired columns, check which ones are equal to 'PASSED' using `DataFrame.eq`, and count the True values using `DataFrame.sum` (pass `axis=1` to count column-wise)

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {'Age':['PASSED'], 'Maturity':['PASSED'],'Gender':['FAILED'], 'Height':['PASSED']}
)
check_columns = ['Age','Maturity','Gender']

frame['results'] = frame[check_columns].eq('PASSED').sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> frame 

      Age Maturity  Gender  Height  results
0  PASSED   PASSED  FAILED  PASSED        2
```

Comment: Solution works as expected. Thanks and now I learn a new keyword! :)

Comment: @JasonX No problem, I'm glad to help! If the answer solves your issue,  please consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ;)